# Why Logistic regression into Spark Mllib does not use Maximum likelihood estimation?

Tags: machine-learning, r, apache-spark, logistic-regression

During comparison estimates/ coefficients in 'R'& Spark Mllib of Logistic regression, It has been observed that estimates are not same.

On further investigation, I found that R & Mllib has different implementations for Logistic regression.

> R's glm is return a maximum likelihood estimate of the model while
>   Spark's LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS is return a regularized model
>   estimate.

Maximum likelihood estimates seems more efficient, as per literature available.

I am curious to know, why Spark Mllib developers has not chosen 'Maximum likelihood estimation' technique?

Comment: In my opinion this question is not duplicate. This question is about why R & Spark Mllib have implemented Logistic regression using 'Maximum likelihood estimation' & 'Regularization model estimation' technique.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're confused. Maximum likelihood is a general technique for giving the most likely parameter estimation. There is no closed solution for maximum likelihood for logistic regression, so both R and Spark must numerically estimate it.

How exactly the likelihood is estimated could be slightly different and might depends on the implementation. For example, Spark prefers to add regularization, R might like to use something else (you'll need to check the documentation).

**Summary**: Both R and Spark try to estimate ML for you. Please check the R documentation on how R do it.